# C++ constructor memory synchronization

Tags: c++, multithreading

Assume that I have code like:

```
void InitializeComplexClass(ComplexClass* c);

class Foo {
 public:
  Foo() {
    i = 0;
    InitializeComplexClass(&c);
  }
 private:
  ComplexClass c;
  int i;
};
```

If I now do something like `Foo f;` and hand a pointer to `f` over to another thread, what guarantees do I have that any stores done by `InitializeComplexClass()` will be visible to the CPU executing the other thread that accesses `f`? What about the store writing zero into `i`? Would I have to add a mutex to the class, take a writer lock on it in the constructor and take corresponding reader locks in any methods that accesses the member?

Update: Assume I hand a pointer over to a bunch of other threads once the constructor has returned. I'm not assuming that the code is running on x86, but could be instead running on something like PowerPC, which has a lot of freedom to do memory reordering. I'm essentially interested in what sorts of memory barriers the compiler has to inject into the code when the constructor returns.

Comment: It really depends on how you are sharing it between threads.

Comment: If `Foo` is initialized once and then read by multiple threads , I suggest handing `const` pointers over to other threads. C++ doesn't really have a deep or transitive `const` but if you ensure other threads can't mutate the members, you'll get away without locks.

Comment: And once you get visibility sorted out, watch out for non-atomic changes in `ComplexClass` if you haven't already protected yourself.

Comment: It depends on how you are using your threads, how you are sharing contexts, and how you are managing your memory, sharing mutable data, and mutexing with each thread.

Comment: @TomekSowiński -- maybe, but that doesn't address the question of the visibility in other threads of the initialization of the object. As others have said, that depends on how the the object gets shared, and const-ness doesn't enter into it until later.

Comment: Constructors aren't special. If you need a memory barrier, then you need a memory barrier.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the other thread to be able to know about your new object, you have to hand over the object / signal other thread somehow. For signaling a thread you write to memory. Both x86 and x64 perform all memory writes in order, CPU does not reorder these operations with regards to each other. This is called `"Total Store Ordering"`, so CPU write queue works like "first in first out".

Given that you create an object first and **then** pass it on to another thread, these changes to memory data will also occur in order and the other thread will always see them in the same order. By the time the other thread learns about the new object, the contents of this object was guaranteed to be available for that thread even earlier (if the thread only somehow knew where to look).

In conclusion, you do not have to synchronise anything this time. Handing over the object **after** it has been initialised is all the synchronisation you need.

**Update:** On non-TSO architectures you do not have this TSO guarantee. So you need to synchronise. Use `MemoryBarrier()` macro (or any interlocked operation), or some synchronisation API. Signalling the other thread by corresponding API causes also synchronisation, otherwise it would not be synchronisation API.

*x86 and x64 CPU may reorder writes past reads, but that is not relevant here. Just for better understanding - writes can be ordered after reads since writes to memory go through a write queue and flushing that queue may take some time. On the other hand, read cache is always consistent with latest updates from other processors (that have went through their own write queue).*

*This topic has been made so unbelievably confusing for so many, but in the end there is only a couple of things a x86-x64 programmer has to be worried about:

- First, is the existence of write queue (and one should not at all be worried about read cache!). 

- Secondly, concurrent writing and reading in different threads to same variable in case of non-atomic variable length, which may cause data tearing, and for which case you would need synchronisation mechanisms. 

- And finally, concurrent updates to same variable from multiple threads, for which we have interlocked operations, or again synchronisation mechanisms.)*

Comment: I'm very aware of TSO and x86, but this particular piece of code should be architecture agnostic and only rely on what is guaranteed by the C++ memory model.

Comment: @eof Some architectures do reorder stores after stores. So then you need synchronisation. If you only were to write to memory to send pointer of new object to other thread, that would not be enough. You should synchronise. Synchronisation consists actually of some interlocked operation, which always also results in write queue flushing. `MemoryBarrier()` macro implements that. On the other hand, if you are going to signal the other thread by using some synchronisation functions or API then that API already does all memory synchronisation for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you do :

```
Foo f;
// HERE: InitializeComplexClass() and "i" member init are guaranteed to be completed
passToOtherThread(&f);
/* From this point, you cannot guarantee the state/members
   of 'f' since another thread can modify it */
```

If you're passing an instance pointer to another thread, you need to implement guards in order for both threads to interact with the same instance. If you ONLY plan to use the instance on the other thread, you do not need to implement guards. However, do not pass a stack pointer like in your example, pass a new instance like this:

```
passToOtherThread(new Foo());
```

And make sure to delete it when you are done with it.